# Rpm scriptlet failes in curl command

Tags: rpm

I've run into an extremely strange problem when using a rpm postinstall scriptlet on Redhat 6 and 7.

The scriptlet need to do a curl get request to a localhost url. The complete request is:

curl -sk https://127.0.0.1:8091/upgrade

If I run the postinstall by hand it works perfectly, but as part or rpm it fails. With the help of strace I found the failure is due to that curl uses a asynchronous connect and the poll. The poll, when running rpm, returns POLLHUP.

There is an even stranger twist to this. If I put a sleep 1 just before the curl, then it works!

Needless to say, I'm not happy with this "solution". Adding a sleep to scripts is normally a sure sign you are not understanding a problem.

Anyone out there who has the faintest idea what is going on here? How can it differ when the script is run by rpm? How can a sleep before the curl do any difference at all? Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Script are executed in POSIX compability mode. While if you run it from command line, the mode is usually off. That is only difference I know. Still I have no idea how it can affect curl.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually tested running in POSIX mode standalone, but it still works fine running standalone  then. I went trough all shell options and shell variables I could find that differ and tried anything that sounded even remotely possible. Nothing made any difference.

Comment: RPM itself doesn't do anything particularly different running scripts (except perhaps attaching stdin to /dev/null). There _MIGHT_ be something going on with signal delivery and starting a child that will depend on whether the child or the parent runs first: that would explain why a sleep(1) changes the behavior. Try running the curl command with … < /dev/stdin and perhaps with signals trapped. Or live with "sleep 1" ;-)